# Linux websphere deployment failed "WASX7017E:

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

This is wsadmin traceout log

```
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java)
    at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine$BSFPythonInterpreter.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.executeScript(AbstractShell.java:1214)
    at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.run(AbstractShell.java:2271)
    at com.ibm.ws.scripting.WasxShell.main(WasxShell.java:1108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:379)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:150)  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ffdc.Manager
    at com.ibm.ws.management.util.RasUtils.logException(RasUtils.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.util.RasUtils.logException(RasUtils.java:110)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.ArchiveDeploymentInfo.createModuleConfig(ArchiveDeploymentInfo.java:503)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentInfo.getModuleConfig(AppDeploymentInfo.java:337)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.ArchiveDeploymentInfo.createDefaultBindings(ArchiveDeploymentInfo.java:792)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.handlePreferences(AppDeploymentController.java:521)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.<init>(AppDeploymentController.java:359)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.<init>(AppDeploymentController.java:288)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:137)
    ... 63 more
```

---

```
WASX7093I: Issuing message: "WASX7017E: Exception received while running file ".py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ffdc.Manager]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ffdc.Manager
```

i am getting this error while deploying and the script is python.....can any one help me

Comment: Looks like some configuration/classpath issue. How are you invoking the script?

Comment: script was invoking by ant wsadmin -lang jython -f scriptfile

Comment: Try to invoke same script directly by `wsadmin` from `profile_root\bin`, not by ant, and see if it make any difference.

Comment: I ment `profile_root\bin\wsadmin -lang jython -f scriptfile`, without ant.